# How do I use org.osgi.service.prefs.Preferences.clear()

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

I'm trying to load and save some simple preferences using `org.osgi.service.prefs.Preferences`. The first save worked, but changes I make in subsequent runs fail to change the file. Looking at the [API](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/service/prefs/Preferences.html) and at [a Vogella article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePreferences/article.html), I think I'm doing the right steps. When I run in debug mode, after I call `clear()`, I still see the same children key/value pairs. Further, after I flush the preferences, the file on disk doesn't change. Do I have to call `flush()` to make this work? (It seems silly that I should have to flush to disk to change something in memory -- and it doesn't help).

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code for saving my descriptors (note that this is shamelessly copied from "Eclipse Rich Client Platform" by McCaffer, Lemieux, and Aniszczyk with some small modifications to update the API for Eclipse 3.8.1):

```
Preferences preferences = ConfigurationScope.INSTANCE.getNode(Application.PLUGIN_ID);
preferences.put(LAST_USER, connectionDetails.getUserId());
Preferences connections = preferences.node(SAVED);
try {
    connections.clear();
    //preferences.flush();
} catch (BackingStoreException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
preferences = ConfigurationScope.INSTANCE.getNode(Application.PLUGIN_ID);
connections = preferences.node(SAVED);
for (Iterator<String> it = savedDetails.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    String name = it.next();
    ConnectionDetails d = (ConnectionDetails) savedDetails.get(name);
    Preferences connection = connections.node(name);
    connection.put(SERVER, d.getServer());
    connection.put(PASSWORD, d.getPassword());
}
try {
    preferences.flush();
} catch (BackingStoreException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preferences must be flushed in order to properly apply modifications, i.e. you have to call `flush()`. Some operations may auto-flush but that's an implementation detail you shouldn't rely on. Also, `clear()` only removes keys on the selected node. In order to remove a node and all its children, `removeNode()` must be called.

```
// get node "config/plugin.id"
// note: "config" identifies the configuration scope used here
final Preferences preferences = ConfigurationScope.INSTANCE.getNode("plugin.id");

// set key "a" on node "config/plugin.id"
preferences.put("a", "value");

// get node "config/plugin.id/node1"
final Preferences connections = preferences.node("node1");

// remove all keys from node "config/plugin.id/node1"
// note: this really on removed keys on the selected node
connections.clear();

// these calls are bogous and not necessary
// they get the same nodes as above
//preferences = ConfigurationScope.INSTANCE.getNode("plugin.id");
//connections = preferences.node("node1");

// store some values to separate child nodes of "config/plugin.id/node1"
for (Entry<String, ConnectionDetails> e : valuesToSave.entrySet()) {
    String name = e.getKey();
    ConnectionDetails d = e.getValue();
    // get node "config/plugin.id/node1/<name>"
    Preferences connection = connections.node(name);
    // set keys "b" and "c"
    connection.put("b", d.getServer());
    connection.put("c", d.getPassword());
}

// flush changes to disk (if not already happend)
// note: this is required to make sure modifications are persisted
// flush always needs to be called after making modifications
preferences.flush();
```

Comment: removeNode did the trick. What ended up working was adding preferences.node("node1").removeNode() immediately before the line final Preferences connections = preferences.node("node1"); Thanks, gunnar.